# Image in front of sentence - DIV

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to put some image or icon right in front of "Estimate delivery date" that is generated by: "rp_estimated_date"

[image]

```
            $response = $this->pregReplaceDate($estDay, $response);



        return '<div class="rp_estimated_date">' . $response . '</div>';
    }

    public function pregReplaceDate($estDay, $response)
    {
        $this->estDay = $estDay;
        $response = preg_replace_callback("/{(.*?)([+-])(.*?)}/", array($this, 'callbackPregReplace'), $response);
        return $response;
    }
```

Any idea how to put the image inside that code? Its a small truck icon.
Thank you :)

Comment: _"that is generated by: "rp_estimated_date""_ - How is that image generated and when? The question is super unclear.

Comment: If you want to change it, I'd probably suggest looking at the CSS declaration for `rp_estimated_date`

Comment: You can use css or just update your code from this

return '<div class="rp_estimated_date">' . $response . '</div>';

to this
return '<div class="rp_estimated_date"><img  src="truck.ico" />' . $response . '</div>';

Comment: ustmaestro, thank you so much! :) Works great!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a CSS rule:

```
.rp_estimated_date::before {
    background-image: url(icon.png);
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

or using Font-Awesome icons and a CSS rule.

Comment: Works great too (besides ustmaestro answer). Thank you.